# Create new data frame using intercepts of multiple linear regression in R

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, lapply

I have a data frame with about 200 columns and it looks like this:

```
d1 <- structure(list(Date=c(2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014),
                x1=c(NA, NA, 17L, 29L, 27L, 10L), x2=c(30L, 19L, 22L, 20L, 11L,
                24L), x3=c(NA, 23L, 22L, 27L, 21L, 26L), x4=c(30L, 28L, 23L,
                24L, 10L, 17L), x5=c(12L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 30L, 26L)),
                 row.names=c(NA, 6L), class="data.frame")
```

Output:

```
 Date x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1 2012 NA 30 NA 30 12
2 2012 NA 19 23 28 18
3 2013 17 22 22 23 17
4 2013 29 20 27 24 16
5 2014 27 11 21 10 30
6 2014 10 24 26 17 26
```

I now want to run linear regressions for each year separately and a create **a new data frame** only with the intercepts for each variable x1 to x4 for each year. My independent variable is x5.

like this:

```
 Time x1 x2 x3 x4 
1 2012 Interceptx1 Interceptx2  Interceptx3 Interceptx4 
2 2013 Interceptx1 Interceptx2  Interceptx3 Interceptx4 
3 2014 Interceptx1 Interceptx2  Interceptx3 Interceptx4
```

I tried `lms <- lapply(2:5, function(x) lm(d1[,x] ~ d1$x5))` and `df <- data.frame(sapply(lms, coef))`
but this runs the regression over the whole time period. My data frame contains 200 columns and i'm therefore looking for a efficient way to create this new data frame.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you define what you mean by intercept? Do you mean from the output of `lm()`? Also what combinations of variables do you  want to train the model on?

Comment: If you're running linear regressions by year, and you want your dependent variable to be the `xn` columns, what will the independent variable be?
e.g. `lm(x1 ~ ?, data = d1)`

Comment: I edited my post. @Rohit With intercept I mean the intercept which I get from `df <- data.frame(sapply(lms, coef))`.

Comment: @r.bot My independent variable is x5. So the regressions by year in my example would be: `lm(x1 ~ x5, data = d1)` , `lm(x2 ~ x5, data = d1)` , `lm(x3 ~ x5, data = d1)` , `lm(x4 ~ x5, data = d1)`

Comment: There is a package called broom for doing this.

Comment: @Seth The tidy function from the broom package does not work with a list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on some other work I've done. I'm sure it's possible to clean it up into a purely purrr solution and would welcome any suggestions along those lines.

I've had to make some changes to your data as the `NA` values were causing it to break.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

d1 <- structure(list(cyear=c(2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014),
                     x1=c(5L, 5L, 17L, 29L, 27L, 10L), 
                     x2=c(30L, 19L, 22L, 20L, 11L,24L), 
                     x3=c(5L, 23L, 22L, 27L, 21L, 26L), 
                     x4=c(30L, 28L, 23L,24L, 10L, 17L), 
                     x5=c(12L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 30L, 26L)),
                row.names=c(NA, 6L), class="data.frame")

models <- nest(d1, -cyear)
str(models)

reg_vars <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")

# The following loops through each of the independent
for(i in 1:length(reg_vars)){
  var_mdl <- rlang::sym(paste0(reg_vars[i], "_mdl")) # create the name of a model
  var_res <- rlang::sym(paste0(reg_vars[i], "_res")) # create the name of the results
  formula = as.formula(paste0(reg_vars[i], " ~ x5")) # create the regression formula
  print(formula)

  models <- models %>%
    mutate(
# create the model as an element in the nested data
      !!var_mdl := map(data, ~ lm(formula, data = ., na.action = "na.omit")), 
# tidy the model results into an element
      !!var_res := map(!!var_mdl, tidy)
    )
}
models

reg_vars2 <- paste0(reg_vars, "_res")
reg_vars2

# clean up ####
# this will extract the regression results into a new data frame
for(i in 1:length(reg_vars2)){
  if(i == 1){
    results <- rlang::sym(reg_vars2[i])
    out_df <- models %>% 
      select(cyear, !!results) %>% 
      unnest(!!results)  
  }
  results <- rlang::sym(reg_vars2[i])
  temp_df <- models %>% 
    select(cyear, !!results) %>% 
    unnest(!!results)
  out_df <- bind_rows(out_df, temp_df)
}

head(out_df)
```